# The criterion of extracting frames from videos for video captioning

Tags: video, lstm

For video captioning, we need to input the video frames into Recurrent Neural Network. If we are provided with videos, what is the standard criterion for extracting frames, such as the frame sampling rate and the image resolution requirement.

I am also wondering, when we do video captioning, do we firstly extract all frames for the videos them saving them as input, or we extract frames in the same time with processing them.

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear from your question so its probably worth mentioning that Captions and Subtitles are generally stored in a separate file from the video itself - i.e. they are not added to the video stream directly. Its also worth noting that most video containers (e.g. an MP4 file) will have separate video and audio tracks.

Depending on the type of captions you want to add the approach may be different - for example if the captions are simple descriptive notes then they are often added manually to be presented at whatever point in the video the editor chooses.

If the captions are to provide a transcript of the speech then they obviously will have to line up with the audio and video streams and will generally be generated from the audio stream and use its time stamps.

There are multiple different standards for captions in different regions and in different deployments, but some of the most common are:

- SMPTE-TT
- TTML

Generally, whatever the format, there will be a mechanism to associate a caption (if required) with any frame of the video - i.e. a timecode to allow the player link a particular video frame with a particular caption.